# Can not run in DEV environment

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php, bundle, environment

I write you because I have a problem to run my project Symfony 4 DEV environment. Indeed, I have the impression that this one does not turn correctly because:

- when I make a modification it is not visible immediately and I usually have to empty the caches to see them
- the profiler and the associated "black bar" do not appear and return a 404 (I have the body tags in my base.htm.twig)
- he does not see "immediately" the roads that I created

I installed the profiler via the following command `composer require profiler --dev` and I am in web server (directly on my NDD and my server).

I also have the variable APP_ENV in dev and it shows me well "dev" when I display it directly in a twig via `{{app.environment}}`

I hope that my explanations are clear enough and that you will be able to help me. thank you in advance

ps: sorry for my English, but I'm on Google Translate ;)

EDIT : I found the solution with the help of someone on Symfony slack ... I did not install the apache-pack bundle which created a .htaccess file in the public folder and manages the rewrites of url ... that's why my roads were not found.
For my defense, I did not see this bundle anywhere in the documentation

Comment: I think I'll try a reinstall and if nothing happens I will choose a symfony 3

Answer (score 1):

The first you have to install `symfony/dotenv` ([dotenv](https://github.com/symfony/dotenv))
In the `.env` follow this:

```
APP_ENV=dev
```

If you have not install `symfony/dotenv`

```
composer require symfony/dotenv
```

You can read about this here https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dotenv.html

Also you have to follow `config/packages/dev/web_profiler.yaml`:

```
web_profiler:
    toolbar: true
    intercept_redirects: false

framework:
    profiler: { only_exceptions: false }
```

Comment: I do not understand. My .env file is well executed since when I use in my twig {{ app.environnement }} I get "DEV". Or it has nothing to do and I say a stupidity?

Comment: `###> symfony/framework-bundle ###
APP_ENV=dev
APP_SECRET=*************************
#TRUSTED_PROXIES=127.0.0.1,127.0.0.2
#TRUSTED_HOSTS=localhost,example.com
###< symfony/framework-bundle ###`

Comment: and

`###> doctrine/doctrine-bundle ###
# Format described at http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/configuration.html#connecting-using-a-url
# For an SQLite database, use: "sqlite:///%kernel.project_dir%/var/data.db"
# Configure your db driver and server_version in config/packages/doctrine.yaml
DATABASE_URL=mysql://*****:*****@127.0.0.1:3306/*****
###< doctrine/doctrine-bundle ###`

Comment: I think I'll try a reinstall and if nothing happens I will choose a symfony 3

Comment: Have you installed `twig` bundle?

Comment: twig.yalm in /config/packages ?

twig:
    paths: ['%kernel.project_dir%/templates']
    debug: '%kernel.debug%'
    strict_variables: '%kernel.debug%'

Comment: And Also can you show `config/packages/dev/web_profiler.yaml`?

Comment: web_profiler:
    toolbar: true
    intercept_redirects: false

framework:
    profiler: { only_exceptions: false }

Comment: ( is it possible to use return line in stack comment , )

Comment: Still nothing ... I installed dotenv and checked again the config / packages / dev / web_profiler.yaml file but still nothing. I create routes and they are not taken into account (except index that exists by default) and I do not have the webprofiler ... nothing ... as if the routing was not taken into account

Comment: Same things if I use annotations for route... nothing

Comment: So now remove vendor `rm -rf vendor/* & composer install` then try

Comment: Are you using any caching (`opcache` or `memcache`)?

Comment: I do not know, I'm on shared hosting ... is there a way to find out?

Comment: To continue searching, I installed a new virgin symfony on my local machine (ubuntu) and I have exactly the same result

Comment: To be honest I would never have found alone. But it is true that I did not see anything on this side in the doc :(

Answer (score 0):

It's not mandatory added `APP_ENV=dev` to your .env.

In Symfony 4 you can see in `public/index.php` this

```
if (!isset($_SERVER['APP_ENV'])) {
    if (!class_exists(Dotenv::class)) {
        throw new \RuntimeException('APP_ENV environment variable is not defined. You need to define environment variables for configuration or add "symfony/dotenv" as a Composer dependency to load variables from a .env file.');
    }
    (new Dotenv())->load(__DIR__.'/../.env');
}

$env = $_SERVER['APP_ENV'] ?? 'dev';
```

So if you APP_ENV is empty also you environment use is dev, but it's better use `APP_ENV` in `.env`

Comment: I actually think that I have two distinct problems: that of the profiler in error 404 and that of the environment of DEV ... in order to advance I would like to be sure that I am not in environment DEV without knowing it. I say that it does not work because when I have an error (routing for example) I "just" a 404 error and not a symfony error with explanations etc etc ... confirm that there is a concern and that I should have such a report on a simple routing error (red background for example)

Comment: I think I'll try a reinstall and if nothing happens I will choose a symfony 3